# How to build a object back along with it's entire nesting using just the snapshots available in javers?

Tags: javers

I have a deeply nested object and I am changing one of properties inside the nesting, when I audit it with Javers it fragments the object and stores it in various snapshots. Now I want to build it back with all changes, so as to get the change and state of object at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Shadows (see https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#query-for-shadows) offer the most natural view on data history. Thanks to JaVers magic, you can see historical versions of your domain objects reconstructed from Snapshots.